# JavaScript/jQuery solution for looping through JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this kind of JSON sent from PHP:

```
{"status":"error","message":"Firstname is invalid"}{"status":"error","message":"Lastname is invalid"}{"status":"success","message":"Middle name is fine"}
```

Ajax is retrieving me that in the success thingy:

```
success:function(data){
data=JSON.parse(data);
//need to loop trough data here
}
```

so the problem is that I need to console.log(data.status /* AND */ data.message) at once.
(ignore the comment above)

So in the JSON example above I want to be able to console.log the following:

(1) error Firstname is invalid
(2) error Lastname is invalid
(3) success Middle name is fine

(the above numbers in "()" just means how it should look like in the console thingy in chrome. I don't need to have them actually numbered)

////////

What I am actually trying to accomplish is to display the success/error messages with alrtify.js based on status.value (wither success or error). I don't want to display them  all in one notification. I want each of the error/success appear as separate notification. I need to loop through them for that.

Comment: That is invalid JSON text, you should be getting an error when calling parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look on your JSON format. It should be like :

```
[{"status":"error","message":"Firstname is invalid"},{"status":"error","message":"Lastname is invalid"},{"status":"success","message":"Middle name is fine"}];
```

So ultimately you will be able to loop.

```
var data = [{"status":"error","message":"Firstname is invalid"},    
            {"status":"error","message":"Lastname is invalid"},    
            {"status":"success","message":"Middle name is fine"}];

for(var i in data)
{
 console.log(data[i].message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you are actually receiving is an array rather than that invalid JSON that you've shown there:

```
success:function(data){
    data=JSON.parse(data); // you probably shouldn't be using this line
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.status + ' ' + item.message);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works like a charm for me.
Plase pay attention, that in my string objects are divided by comma, instead of yours '{"status":"error","message":"Firstname is invalid"}{"status":"error","message":"Lastname is invalid"}{"status":"success","message":"Middle name is fine"}'

```
var data = '[{"status":"error","message":"Firstname is invalid"}, {"status":"error","message":"Lastname is invalid"}, {"status":"success","message":"Middle name is fine"}]';

var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

parsedData.forEach(function(item, index) {
    alert(item.status + " - " + item.message);
    console.log(item.status + " - " + item.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data){
    data=JSON.parse(data); // you probably shouldn't be using this line
    var data = $.parseJSON(item);
        for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            var obj = data[i];
            var status = obj.status;
            var message = obj.message;

        }
    });
```